# Top Performance PHP + HTTPD + OPCACHE

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, lighttpd, opcache

I'm trying to figure out what would be the most performing configuration to host a PHP website on Amazon EC2.

Which webserver? (Apache, Lighttpd, nginx)?
Which PHP module? mod_php, FastCgi?
Which OpCache? (xcache, APC, eAccelerator, Varnish)

What would you recommended setup would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It depends on your application running on the server. Needs much more memory or cpu or both?
2. [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) + [PHP-FPM](http://php-fpm.org/) + Varnish-Cache is a good solution if you can use them effectively.

Comment: I would use it with either Wordpress or ForkCMS.

Comment: I also saw around that there are guides to setup nginx + php-fpm + apc + varnish. Does it make sense to add both varnish and apc?
And what about memcache, does it make sense to have that too?

Comment: No it doesn't. There is no need to use apc in that configuration, because varnish is already caching pages and serves then from memory. I also use Redis for memory based object caching which is better than memcache i think

Comment: Varnish can't do opcode caching.